# How can I use functions to solve the following problem in Python? (edited)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Define a function to filter the marks from the tuple "marks" that are greater than 40 and print corresponding names from the "names" tuple.

```
names = ('John','Sharon','Jack','Annie')
marks = (32,50,75,12)
```

I'm new to python and I've been trying to do this but not getting the required output.

My steps:

```py
tnames = ('John','Sharon','Jack','Annie')
tmarks = (32,50,75,12)

zipper=dict(zip(tnames,tmarks))
print(zipper)

get_marks=list(filter(lambda x:x>40,tmarks))
print(get_marks)

res=[]

for i in range(0,4):
    if i in get_marks==i in zipper.values():
        res.append(zipper.keys(i))     

print(res)
```

Comment: Please share what you've been trying and where do you get stuck?

Comment: @DanielHao thanks for your suggestion, I just added my steps

Comment: Just to confirm - what's your desired output from the sample?  Don't want to guess...

Comment: @DanielHao The desired output should be Sharon and Jack.

Comment: You may wish to explain what the variables and your code is attempting to do. I think I can see you're trying to get a certain key, but `keys()` doesn't take arguments. What's important is to explain what you are attempting to do, and what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without `filter()`:

```
def filterMarks(names, marks):
    result = []
    for i, mark in enumerate(marks):
        if (mark > 40):
            result.append(names[i])
    return result
```

As a list comprehension:

`[names[i] for i, mark in enumerate(marks) if mark > 40]`

Usage:

```
names = ('John','Sharon','Jack','Annie')
marks = (32,50,75,12)

print(filterMarks(names, marks))

print([names[i] for i, mark in enumerate(marks) if mark > 40 ])
```

Output:

```
['Sharon', 'Jack']
['Sharon', 'Jack']
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a bunch. Although I must admit I'll have to look up how enumerate works because I have no idea about it. I'll try approaching it without enumerate in the filtermarks function now and see if I can make it work perhaps.

Comment: Great! Please remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem :) As a hint, to avoid using `enumerate`, you can iterate over the `range(len(marks))` instead, and then access each item by the iterated index. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah I was also thinking of using range(len(marks)). I have solved it now. Thanks for everything.  Do you have any idea though why my previous attempt ( the one I mentioned in the question) didn't work? It's giving an error saying --->'dict' object is not callable.

Answer (score 2):

You could more easily do this with a list comprehension, rather than using `filter()`:

```
output = [name for (name, mark) in zip(names, marks) if mark > 40]
# ['Sharon', 'Jack']
```

Ironically, using `filter()` would require more steps and  be less idiomatic:

```
output = [tup[0] for tup in filter(lambda t: t[1] > 40, zip(names, marks))]
# ['Sharon', 'Jack']
```

Comment: I will interpret the `filter out` as ` remove` those over age 40?  If that's the case, this should be changed to `mark <  40`  instead and save to the final list?  Req. is not clear - it depends what's the desired output...

Comment: Thanks much! Totally agree with you. Using filter() doesn't make much sense here.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by just checking the `marks` directly like this. As some posts indicated already. Don't have to use the built-in `filter`.

First step is to get the `tuple` pair from `zip` then you can do comparison on the 2nd item - the mark, and `filter-out` those you don't want.

```
# use the given sample data 
senior = [name for (name, m) in zip(tnames, tmarks) if m > 40]
junior = [name for (name, m) in zip(tnames, tmarks) if m < 40]

print(f' Seniors: {senior} ')  # output both names of Sr.
print(f' Juniors: {junior} ')  # just output the names
```

Comment: Thanks!
On second thought, I think the question wants me to create a user-defined function, pass the two tuples and call the function to give the desired output. @zr0gravity7 solved this using the enumerate() in their defined function 'FilterMarks' but I'm thinking of doing the same thing what 
zr0gravity7 did without using enumerate()

Comment: It's quite simple, do you want to try it first, and also edit your original PO to reflect the `new` request?

Comment: I'll give it a go and update if I need any help. Thanks though, you're pretty awesome.

Comment: You could upvote for the post that you think it's helpful to you. As a token of appreciation...

Comment: Yeah I've been trying to upvote the answers but the website isn't allowing me to, because I have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: Just try to post more interesting questions and to learn here.  ;-)

Comment: Yes I hope to. I upvoted the answers as I have 17 reps now :) And hey I solved my question without using enumerate()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234707/discussion-between-daniel-hao-and-shieldbreaker).